# How does the tangent line according to calculus correlates to the classic intuition of a line that only passes through one point of the curve?

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Sorry if my English is wrong.

In calculus, given a function $f$, derivable at $x_0$, the tangent line to the curve at $x_0$ is

$$t(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

How can I convince myself that this line corresponds to the intuition of "a line is tangent to a curve if it intersects the curve one and only one time". I think you can get a segment of line that verifies this for all non-linear functions.

The reason I say segment of line, and not line is because, for example if $f(x)=x^3$, the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $x_0=-0.5$, $t(x)=\frac{\left(3x\ +\ 1\right)}{4}$intersects the curve at $x=-0.5$ and $x=1$.

How to prove that $t$ is such line, and no other? Thank you.

Comment: The important thing about the tangent line in calculus is that it's the best local linear approximation to the graph of a function $f$ at a given point. Whether or not the tangent line intersects the graph of $f$ at more than one point doesn't matter.

Comment: Without calculus the only definition of tangent is limited to tangent of a circle and that is what one learns in a typical geometry class. The ancient geometers dealt with conics and their tangents in ways which mimic the notion of limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not actually the definition of the tangent line, because for example the line $x = 0$ touches $y = x^3$ at only one point, but is not a tangent line.

A better version might be "the slope of the line passing through two points of the curve, in the limit as the two points approach each other and become one."  It's a much more specific criterion.

Comment: But, is it not true that if there is a tangent line to the curve at $x_0$ then its equation is the one above?

Comment: Yes, and that's where that formula comes from.  Try drawing for yourself a curve, and mark $x$ on the horizontal axis and $f(x)$ on the vertical, and then to one side, $x+h$ on the horizontal and $f(x+h)$ on the vertical.  Connect the dots, and the slope is $$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{x+h-x}$$ and the limit of that is the derivative.